# jQuery treetable

Tags: jquery, treeview

Таблица выводится вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на странице 3 вкладке, в первой вот эта таблица, во второй и третьей такие по структуре таблицы, но отличаются количеством столбцов и другие цифры.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при раскрытии/скрытии строк в одной из таблиц, то же самое действие происходило и в других таблицах для тех же строк.

Целый день бьюсь, но ничего толкового на ум не приходит. Додумался только подставлять нужные классы в другие таблицы, но при повторном скрытии/раскрытии строк не все строки показываются. Необходимо писать костыль который будет перебирать элементы искать потомков сверять классы и тд.... Вообщем как-то не очень помоему. Может есть пути по проще или другие библиотеки для этого?

При клике на иконку в первой таблице выполняется вот такой код:

```
$("table#spisok tr td span.indenter").click(function(event) {
          var el = $(event.currentTarget);
          var tr = el.parents('tr');
          var data_tt_id = tr.attr('data-tt-id');
          // смещение в пикселях
          var paddingLeft = 19;

          // определяем уровень вложенности строки
          var data_tt_parent_id = tr.attr('data-tt-parent-id');
          if (data_tt_parent_id === undefined)
            level = 1;
          else {
            d = data_tt_parent_id.split("-");
            level = d.length + 1;
          }
          console.log(level);
          var cl = (level != 3) ? 'collapsed' : '';

          // если строка свернута
          if ($("table#spisok_moving tr[data-tt-id='"+data_tt_id+"']").hasClass('collapsed') && $("table#spisok_month tr[data-tt-id='"+data_tt_id+"']").hasClass('collapsed')) {
            // разворачиваем строку
            $("table#spisok_moving tr[data-tt-id='"+data_tt_id+"']")
                .removeClass('collapsed')
                .addClass('expanded');

            // показываем дочерние строки
            $("table#spisok_moving tr[data-tt-parent-id='"+data_tt_id+"']")
                .addClass(cl)
                .css({'display':'table-row'});

            // смещаем дочерние строки и добавляем икону +
            $("table#spisok_moving tr[data-tt-parent-id='"+data_tt_id+"'] span.indenter")
                .html("<a href='#' title='Expand'>&nbsp;</a>")
                .css({'padding-left':(paddingLeft * level) + 'px'});
          } else {
            // если строка развернута
            if ($("table#spisok_moving tr[data-tt-id='" + data_tt_id + "']").hasClass('expanded')) {
              // сворачиваем строку
              $("table#spisok_moving tr[data-tt-id='" + data_tt_id + "']")
                  .removeClass('expanded')
                  .addClass('collapsed');
            }
          }
        });
```

Открывает/скрывает строки во второй таблице.
Если в первой таблице закрыть строку Архангельский ф-л и затем открыть заново, то первая таблица будет выглядеть ка на картинке, но во второй таблице строка Участок 3 так и остается скрытой.

Сама таблица создается по аякс запросу

```
$table.= "
            <tr data-tt-id='$count_region-$count_filial' data-tt-parent-id='$count_region' class='color_arfs2'>
                    <td>
```

и тд....

Comment: Где Ваш код? Желательно создать минимально рабочий пример с тем, что есть и тем, что хотелось бы.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос